# Conflict of personality

Tags: reference-request, parents

Is calling Shia and Wahhabis non Muslims, calling lavish Quran kawanis (collective reading naats) etc, I am opposed to it as I have believe that Allah should be only one who has right to call anyone non Muslims, and feeding poor instead of calling Quran kawani etc. 
Recently I had son and after many name consideration, I choose one. Although I asked all so no one is left behind but nothing yet. So I decided to go with what my Mrs and me agree. Now point has come that I can see that my in laws don't like my son's name, and kind of make fun of the name.

Comment: May I ask what is your son name

Comment: @servant salar, but some relatives put me down saying it sounds like salad

Answer (score 1):

As a Reference from the Qur'an one could quote the Verse ([49:11](http://legacy.quran.com/49/11))

This Verse talks about mocking giving bad nicknames and making fun of believers. Scholars say if somebody makes fun of Allah and his Prophet he is considered as kafir and some adopt this fatwa to those who make fun of believers (because of their belief) too.

Al-Qurtobi said in his tafsir of the part

> Wretched is the name of disobedience after [one's] faith.

Who gave his brother (bad) nicknames is a *fasiq* (disobedient).

Well our Prophet (peace be upon him) himself gave to his sahaba (good) (May Allah be pleased with them) nicknames, like [Abu Huraira](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abu_Hureyrah) who's real name is Abd-ar-rahman ibn Sakhr ad-Dawsi, he called his companion Abu Bakr as-Siddiq because he always trusted him, he called his cousin [Ali ibn Abi Talib](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ali#Titles) "Abu Torab=Father of Soil" because he found him one night sleeping on the soil of the mosque and so on.

A Muslim shouldn't mock on a Muslim or abuse him in any case and should call him by if so by a nickname he likes (kunya in Arabic)

Here are some references about [abusing](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/92/27) and also [this](https://sunnah.com/muslim:1661c) , about [harsh words](https://sunnah.com/riyadussalihin:1555) in general, and about calling a Muslim by the [name he prefers](http://sunnah.com/adab/34/9) (this is qualified as da'if/weak but there are other ahadith which seem to support it's content).

**On** the other hand a child has a right over it's parents especially the father one of them is giving him/her a good name!

As we find in a weak hadith which is quoted with slightly differences in al-Hilya (of abu Na'im) and other Versions quoted by ibn al-Mubarak, A-Daraqutni and al-Bayhaqi which is/are reported by abu Huraira (May Allah be pleased with him) (My own translation so take it with care):

> The Messenger of Allah (peace be upon him) said: a child has the following rights over his/her father: give him/her a good name, teach him/her the book and marry him/her if he lived to see.

In some [Versions of this Hadith](http://www.alwakei.com/news/13684/index.html): instead of marrying him, you may find educating him/her ...

> عن أبي هريرة - رضي الله عنه – قال : قال رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم :
> ( حق الولد على والده أن يحسن اسمه ، ويعلمه الكتاب ، ويزوجه إن أدرك )

All these Versions have "giving a good name" in common, so this might strengthen the weaknesses of this part at least! Not to forget that most -if not all- the contents of these ahadith go ahead with the shari'a as far as i can tell, so the weaknesses seem to me only in the narrator chains!

And Allah knows best!